# How to get a records that have a a certain number of attributes, dependent on the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a project where I have a set of posts, a post has many comments, a post also has a comments_last_checked field and a comment_checking_threshold field. I need to be able to get the posts that have had more comments than their comment_checking_threshold between their comments_last_checked date and the current date. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, since the threshold and the date range will be different for each post.

I have something along the lines of:

```
@posts.joins(:comments
     ).where(comments: { 'comments.created_at > posts.comments_last_checked' }
     ).group('posts.id'
     ).having('COUNT(comments.id) >= posts.comment_checking_threshold')
```

However I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I've now update my code to:

```
@posts.joins(:comments
     ).where('comments.created_at > posts.last_review_date'
     ).group('posts.id'
     ).having('posts.review_threshold >= COUNT(comments.id)')
```

However I now get the error Unknown column 'posts.review_threshold' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try changing the query to

```
Post.joins(:comments)
  .where('comments.created_at BETWEEN posts.comments_last_checked AND ?', Time.now)
  .group('posts.id')
  .having('COUNT(comments.id) >= posts.comment_checking_threshold')
```

> Note: This query is generated as per your given information . Check for proper column names

Comment: Hi I've update my code to you're example, but if I run it the query returns #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000014380108>, but no posts.

Comment: I tried the same in my system and it should give proper result If it's not working then check if your criteria meets what you want

Comment: Maybe you dont have comments within that date range or the threshold is not reached

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help. The query seems to work up to the group clause, however the having clause give an error Unknown column 'posts.comment_checking_threshold' in 'having clause'